# Put two words in a same line if they fit, if not put them in a new line

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

So I have the following question:

I have attributed string contained in a UITextView. Attributed string is contained of two parts - the normal one is ordinary text, and the second part has NSURL in it - so for better visualisation it would look like:

For more information READ HERE

The problem that I am having is that if the text fits in the one line I must keep it in one line, and if "HERE" falls in second line I must put READ also in the second line.

So, the first case - if all fits

For more information READ HERE

All other cases -

For more information 
READ HERE

I tried to do it with checking if size of the screen is bigger than textfield bounds but it didn't work:

```
if (label.bounds.size.width < size.width) ...
```

I tried also other similar solutions but i think they are all addable on normal UILabels and not modified attributed texts.

If you have any idea how to deal with this I would appreciate it.

Thanks :)

Comment: How about a no-break space(⌥-space) between READ and HERE?

Comment: Thats exactly what i needed! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solution to resolve this.

**First one is to use non-breakable space**

simply add "\u{00a0}" in between click here like **CLICK\u{00a0}HERE**

here is the [link](https://medium.com/@ant_one/using-non-breaking-space-in-swift-or-how-to-prevents-an-automatic-line-break-645647fe44cc)

**Second one is instead of adding space you can add "_" into it.**

e.g.

"CLICK_HERE" and you can replace the color of "_" with clear.

here is the code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var temp : UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let myString = "For more detail information READ_HERE"
        let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString)
        attributedString.setColorForText(textForAttribute: "_", withColor: .clear)
        temp.attributedText = attributedString
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}



extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    func setColorForText(textForAttribute: String, withColor color: UIColor) {
        let range: NSRange = self.mutableString.range(of: textForAttribute, options: .caseInsensitive)

        self.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)

    }

}
```